# Android Dagger updating values outside module

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, object-graph

I am using `dagger` for DI in an android application.
I can provide variables to other classes outside the modules, **but how to update them?**

> **Example: Login**
>
> I need a AuthenticationModule which can **Provide a User**. When the app starts, the User is not logged in, so it is null.
> But after successful authentication, LoginActivity needs to set the
> value of the User to make it accessible through other parts of the app
> via AuthenticationModule.

Simply setting the values of the injected field does not do the job for me.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had simillar problem and I've made something like this:

#### wrapper:

```
class LoggedUserProvider {
    private User user;
    User getLoggedUser() {
        return user;
    }
    void setLoggedUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

#### module:

```
@Module(injects = Endpoint.class)
public class AuthenticationModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    LoggedUserProvider provideLoggedUserProvider() {
        return new LoggedUserProvider();
    }
}
```

After that you can use `@Inject LoggedUserProvider` and just use getter/setter to set which user is currently logged in.

#### OR

If you want to make this without wrapper I guess you would need to make this module:

```
@Module(injects = Endpoint.class)
public class AuthenticationModule {
    @Provides
    User provideUser() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this but don't include this before authorization:

```
@Module(overrides = true)
public class CurrentUserModule {
    User currentUser;
    public CurrentUserModule(User currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    User provideUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }
}
```

then, after authorization add this module to objectGraph (passing logged user to constructor) and recreate whole graph.
That's just idea, I have never make it this way.

Comment: I think so, otherwise you won't be able to use them outside of the `LoggedUserProvider`

Answer (score 1):

By re-assigning the User-object itself over and over again, the **ObjectGraph** cannot pass the newly assigned object to other classes.

I solved the problem by implementing an **`AuthenticationHandler`** which holds the userobject.
So there is only one Object that gets injected which implements methods like `setCurrentUser()`